# Convert.ToString(DateTime) yielding UK format instead of US

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, localization, regional-settings

I'm having an issue where a C# DateTime string is failing to convert to a SQL DateTime because it is mysteriously being formatted as a UK date (dd/MM/yyyy). Here is the series of events:

1. An object is created on a remote server in the US and serialized to xml.
2. The xml is deserialized on a local computer in CA back to an object. The serialized date looks like this: 2011-07-13T09:56:57.0542425
3. The application attempts to save the object to the database calling the previously mentioned stored procedure. It (needlessly) converts the date to a string before passing it as a parameter to the sproc using Convert.ToString(DateTime).
4. The sproc fails with the SqlException "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime" because the string it received for its DateTime typed parameter was in the dd/MM/yyyy format (and the database language is English US).

Now, the code shouldn't be converting the datetime to a string only to be converted back to a datetime in SQL, but this problem just started happening (on more than one computer) after everything was fine for over a year. So I thought the culture of the DB or the OS must have just recently changed causing them to use different date formats. To my surprise, after changing the OS (Windows 7) from English(Canada) to English(US) and restarting, the problem still occurs. To make it even more confusing, the error doesn't happen when when the same type of object is created locally instead of being deserialized, regardless of the regional settings. The only difference is the serialization version happens in a Windows service and the locally created object version happens in a Windows app. They both use their own copy of the assembly that calls Convert.ToString(DateTime) but they are using the same version of that assembly. I am utterly confused.

P.S. .NET 2.0 & SQL Server 2005

Comment: When the date is serialised in step 1, is there any special handling for culture being done? It's possible, when the string is read in, it's making assumptions about the culture the DateTime was created in.

Comment: Why can't you change Step 3 so it doesn't convert a perfectly understandable DateTime to an ambiguous string?  Don't tell me it's embedded SQL.  Use a SqlParameter with type Date .

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know we don't have any code dealing explicitly dealing with culture or localization. Here's how it serializes: 

        public virtual string Serialize()
        {
            FireEvent(EVENT_SERIALIZING, this);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
            System.IO.StringWriter s = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(s, this);
            return s.ToString();
        }
From what I can tell, the DateTime structure doesn't maintain any culture data right? So once it has read it in would it matter?

Comment: @agent-j, I can, but note that I worded the question to avoid that answer ;). I will change it now that I know it's there, but that's at least a month away from making it out to these couple problematic machines that have been working fine. Understanding the cause currently is the quickest route to fixing it. 

P.S. The datetime allows nulls in SQL and the full statement is (_inquiryDate < new DateTime(1870,01,01)?null:Convert.ToString(_inquiryDate)). I'm guessing the original programmer thought it had to be a string to use this syntax with null. I have no idea why 1870,01,01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the service is running under an account which has the wrong regional settings?

If so, then perhaps [these](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Apply-regional-and-language-settings-to-reserved-accounts) instructions from Microsoft might apply.

Comment: That was it. I didn't know accounts could have their own regional settings, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not force the format of the `DateTime.ToString()` using the culture you specifically want-- or specify a custom formatting rule that matches what your SQL functions expect?

For custom formatting you can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) or for culture specific formatting, you can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: I didn't write it, but I'd guess they didn't think about it that carefully when they wrote it. I would rather pass the datetime itself than mess with string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is anything in a `DateTime` beyond a simple 64-bit integer - basically it's the date/time in ticks, and the "kind" encoded in the top couple of bits. So creating a new `DateTime` is created locally. In other words, I'm afraid I doubt your claim about what happens when "the same type of object is created locally".

That's where I'd start investigating - get rid of the database call, but just log the result of calling `Convert.ToString(serializedDateTime)` and `Convert.ToString(new DateTime(2011, 7, 25))` (as an example of a date where the string representation makes it obvious which way round things are). I'd be *really* surprised if you can get that to give two different date formats - one for the value which had been deserialized and one for the value which was created locally.

What "kind" of `DateTime` do you get after deserialization (i.e. the result of fetching the `Kind` property)? With that information you should be able to construct an *exactly* equal `DateTime` value.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Maybe we can swap out an assembly with that logging in it next time I get access to the computer. What I did was modify the stored procedure to accept an nvarchar instead of a datetime, then insert the nvarchar into another table before converting it to a datetime. The nvarchar value was in the dd/mm/yyyy format. I later used the application to save a different type of object that is having the exact same issue and using the same technique, found it was receiving mm/dd/yyyy, and that was when the regional settings were set to English(Canada)...which also seems messed up. The fact

Comment: that it was a different type is a slight risk, but I think its a fairly reasonable assumption. I will verify it next time as well. I don't currently know what the DateTime's Kind is but if I parse the DateTime string in a test app, it's Unspecified.The fact is, in the app I can save a Family object, for instance, but the windows service can't deserialize and save a Family object using the same code. I think it's important to note, the codebase for the windows service and the desktop app has not changed since January and the code directly involved hasn't changed since at least Nov 2010.

Comment: @xr280xr: Sure - there are plenty of different things which can have happened, but I think it's important to isolate the different aspects here: you have the web service providing data, the code in the middle, and the database. If you can reproduce the problem without the web service (by creating the data locally), that eliminates one aspect. If you can reproduce the problem without the database (by logging a string), that eliminates another aspect.